# Wordpress Sort Posts By Category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm outputting all posts in date order and want to add a few buttons that'll allow the user sort them via category.

The two categories I have are "Events" and "News". I'd like the user to be able to click an "Events" button, and have all post disappear other than Events posts, as well as one for "News" and one for "All".

Looking for a code solution over a plugin. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="filter-dropdown">
      <?php $args = array('type' => 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE','orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC','taxonomy' => 'TAXONOMY_NAME' ); ?>
      <?php $terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'TAXONOMY_NAME', 'parent'   => 0 ) );
      $allcats = array();
      ?>
<!-- Nav Tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
              <li class="active" role="presentation">
                <a href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">ALL</a>
              </li>
      <?php  $i=1; 
        $class=''; 
          foreach ($terms as $category) { 
            if ($category->category_parent == 0 && $category->slug != 'all') { 
              $i++; 
                array_push($allcats,$category->slug); 
                  echo '<li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#tab'.$i.'" aria-controls="tab'.$i.'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">'.$category->name.'</a></li>';
            } 
          } 
      ?>
    </ul>
<!-- -->
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <?php $post_type = 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE'; $taxonomy = 'TAXONOMY_NAME'; ?>
<!-- Code to Display All Posts -->
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade active in" role="tabpanel">
          <div class="row">
            <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => $post_type, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'field'    => 'slug', 'terms'    => $allcats, 'include_children' => false, ),),);
              $posts = new WP_Query($args);
              $j = 0;
                if( $posts->have_posts() ){ 
                  while( $posts->have_posts() ) { 
                    $posts->the_post(); 
                      $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full' ); ?>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="tab_pic">
                          <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" />
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="tab_hover">
                            <span class="inner_txt"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  <?php }
                }
            wp_reset_query(); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
<!-- -->
        <?php $i=1; $class=''; 
          foreach( $allcats as $cats ) {
            $postcat= $category->cat_ID; $i++; ?>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <div class="row">
                  <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => $post_type, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy,'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $cats, 'include_children' => false,) ) );
                    $posts = new WP_Query($args); if( $posts->have_posts() ){ while( $posts->have_posts() ) { $posts->the_post();
                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full' ); ?>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="tab_pic">
                          <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="" />
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="tab_hover">
                            <span class="inner_txt"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  <?php } } wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Returned a fatal error.


`Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Query as array in /home/produ325/public_html/eccdev/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:3090 Stack trace: #0`